# AssemblyAlgorithmIdAttribute: Why would anyone use this?

Tags: c#, .net, hash, .net-assembly

[AssemblyAlgorithmIdAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyalgorithmidattribute.aspx)

Why would you care what algorithm the CLR uses to hash the files in your assembly? When would you use this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hash algorithm could depend on the size of files / time required to get hash and picked during compilation time. I.e.:

   - for small files one hash algorithm might perform faster
   - for sparse files some other algorithm
   - for large ones - third one
     etc... - evaluation of the most efficient hashing algorithm could be done once in order to decrease time spent on checks later (although its quite unlikely done in this way :) )
2. AssemblyAlgorithmIdAttribute also provides forward compatibility for future versions of hashing algorithms.
3. It could also depend on framework version - actual algorithm could've changed already since .net 1.1

Comment: I don't understand your #1 and #2 reasons.

Answer (score 1):

May be if I am planning to read assembly from a non CLR program or in other words I am interested in manually reading the contents of assembly I can use the exact hash algorithm to decode the data contained in the assembly.